# x86 assembly directly write to VGA simple OS

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader

I made simple code, that should write to VGA memory.

```
org 07c00h
  mov eax,0xb8000
  mov bx,msg
  call printstr
printstr:


  mov al,byte[bx]
  mov byte[eax],al
  inc eax
  mov byte[eax],1
  inc eax
  inc bx
  cmp byte[bx],0
  je end
  jmp printstr

end:
  jmp end
msg: db "Hello world!",0
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

But instead of writing "Hello world" it does this when i run it in QEMU.
I assembled that using NASM.
[Image](http://2imgs.com/cbd3f2d80b)

I want to overwrite first 12 chars at first line with "Hello world!".

Does anybody know why its giving me this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  mov al,byte[bx]
  mov byte[eax],al
```

`al` is part of `eax`, so by reading a character into `al` you're trashing your screen pointer.

Besides that, shouldn't you be using segmented addressing in your bootloader? Something like this:

```
push 0xb800
pop es
xor di,di
cld
...
stosb ; [es:di] = al, di++
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not using segmented addressing, because i'm not familiar with it, and i'm not sure if i understand it well.

Comment: Well, I've never written an x86 OS or a bootloader, but I would guess that the CPU starts up in real mode, and that you therefore _have_ to use segmented addressing before you've switched over to protected mode.

Comment: It's ok to use 32-bit addressing even in real mode since 386. Only the first 20 (or 21?) bits of the resulting linear address will be used though.